# angular2 component not getting rendered while trying to use angular2-universal-starter

Tags: angular, universal, angular2-template, html-rendering

I am developing an application which helps me **to render static html including angular2 components**.

I have developed few angular2 components.
Now I need to insert them in my static html.

So far I can generate static html successfully.
but when I use selector tags of my angular2 components inside my html,it renders those tags as it is. i.e. **angular2 components are not loaded.**
Previously components were getting loaded correctly using same code.

Following are the code snippets I have used.

**1.app.component.ts**

```js
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'demo.component.html'  
})
export class App {
  name: string = 'Angular Server Rendering Test';    
}
```

**2.demo.component.html**

```
<div>
    {{name}}
</div>
```

**3.client.ts**

```js
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
//import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
// import {bootstrap} from 'angular2-universal-preview';
import {App} from './app/app.component';
bootstrap(App);
```

**4.server.ts**

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as universal from 'angular2-universal-preview';

// Angular 2
import {App} from './app/app.component';

let app = express();
let root = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));

// Express View
app.engine('.ng2.html', universal.ng2engine);
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'ng2.html');

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(root));
var i = 0;
// Routes
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index_new', { app }, function(err,html){
      console.log("------------------My HTML ---------\n"+(i++));
      console.log(html);
      console.log("------------------My HTML ----------");
      res.send(html);
  });
});

// Server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listen on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

**6.index.html**

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular 2 Universal Starter</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading....</app>
    
    <script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/client/bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
     System.config({
     packages: {        
         app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
         }
     });
     System.import('app/client')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the long code snippets.
so when I run this app using `npm start` my application renders html as it is i.e. angular2 components are not getting inside the selector tags.
Below are snapshots of browser & console.
[image: Browser shows this output]

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you made a typo on the following line. You should use `App` instead of `app`. You need to specify here the application component you want to use and not the Express application:

```
res.render('index_new', { App }, function(err,html){
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your directives

Answer (score -2):

Try giving the full template url.

Instead of

```
 templateUrl: 'demo.component.html'
```

use

```
 templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/src/app/template/demo.component.html'
```

Replace **src/app/template/demo.component.html** with your template path.